# What is the right way to find an edge between two vertices?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop

Using tinkerpop [blueprints API](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.3.0/), what is the best way to find if an edge exists between two vertices? I would like to avoid `vertex.getEdges()` and iterate until find the right one.

E.g.: Check if `v1` is friend of `v2`

```
Vertex v1 = g.addVertex(null);
Vertex v2 = g.addVertex(null);
Edge edge = g.addEdge(null, v1, v2, "friends");
Edge edge = g.addEdge(null, v1, v2, "follows");

// Node with lots of edges - Supernode - problem?
List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
for(Edge edge : g.getVertex(v1.getId()).getEdges(Direction.OUT, "friends")){
   if(edge.getVertex(Direction.IN).getId().equals(v2.getId()){
      edges.add(edge);
  }
}
```

Should I use [Vertex Query](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Vertex-Query)?

---

Via gremlin I could do:

```
g.v(v1.getID()).outE("friends").inV.filter{it.id == v2.getID}
```

[Neo4j way:](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.3/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/RelationshipIndex.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.Node,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.Node%29)

```
IndexHits<Relationship> relationships = relationshipIndex().get("type", edgeType, node1, node2);
```

Thanks for the help! 
I am still new to this.

Comment: It seems you're able to fetch it with the core API. Why use the "overhead" of the blueprints API in this case?

Comment: The core API is possible with Neo4j, but with Titan for example, I need to use directly blueprints

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  Use Vertex query and vertex centric indices if possible to improve query times. https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices

Comment: I am also looking for something like `graphContext.testIncidence(projectVertex(), archiveVertex, "uses");`

Comment: [Here's the jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1270).

Comment: Related: [How to remove edge between two vertices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589215/how-to-remove-edge-between-two-vertices)

Answer (score 4):

```
gremlin> g.v(1).bothE.as('x').bothV.retain([g.v(3)]).back('x')
```

Answer (score 4):

The `back` step as used in the answer by [Huangmao Quan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284871/huangmao-quan) is no longer available in Tinkerpop. As I answered already to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35943897/6313877) the following request may apply to more recent versions of the tinkerpop stack.

```
g.V().has('propertykey','value1').outE('thatlabel').as('e').inV().has('propertykey','value2').select('e')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (g.v(1).out('follows').retain([g.v(2)]).hasNext())
{
    println('v(1) follows v(2)')
}
```

**NOTE**: the edge here is unidirectional, i.e. you cannot infer whether v2 follows v1 or not.

**Source**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/Og7Xf8tYbx4/gqBArTw98sAJ

Answer (score 0):

```
g.V(v1).bothE("edge_label").where(otherV().is(v2)
```